# Google Cloud Run not streaming pipe | commands

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ftp, streaming, google-cloud-run

I have a Google Cloud Run server downloading large files from an FTP server into Google Storage.
The files do not fit in the Cloud Run's memory so I tried streaming them

```
wget -nv -O - --ftp-user=my_user --ftp-password=******* 
ftp://lotofdata.com//big_file.txt.gz 
| gzip -d
| mbfuffer -q  -m 50M
| gsutil cp - gs://my_bucket/big_file.txt.gz
```

The stream works perfectly on my MacBook but fails on Cloud Run.
From the logs it seems that the pipes aren't streaming there, it's trying to do the commands sequentually. Is there anything special on Cloud Run's OS?
I am using Docker python:3.7.4-slim-buster

Comment: Does the container run on your MacBook? Edit your question with your container Dockerfile and application. If you are trying to use Cloud Run to run a batch script, you will have problems. Cloud Run requires an HTTP Request/Response system setup similar to a simple web server. Look into frameworks like Flask.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have large files from an FTP server, I think you need to use
   a VM instance with a large memory size as per your requirement, Then run your script
2. OR can mount your FTP server to VM then use gsutil
3. OR You need to increase cloud run memory [cloud run memory docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits)
4. If your FTP server is hosted on on-premise data center then use[GCP storage transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview)